# why javascript protocol decode the URL automatically?

Tags: javascript, php, urlencode, urldecode

I am confused about why javascript protocol decodes the encoded URL, for example:

```
    <a href="javascript:myFunction('%3DcDO4w67epn64o76');">press</a> 
    function myFunction(id)
    {
        alert(id); //it will generate =cDO4w67epn64o76
    }
```

I am using these strings in encryption and decryption.

Please provide me with a real reason and a solution (the reason is very important for me), I know I can replace the (=) sign, but I am afraid of the rest of the encoded strings to be decoded also by the wrapper.

**Note**: in php, the GET, REQUEST Global variables, the url is decoded automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's in an `href` attribute, where URLs are expected, so the browser is "normalizing" the URI-encoding of the "URL" (which is using the `javascript` pseudo-scheme).

You can put it in a *different* attribute and then get that, like so:

```js
function myFunction(element) {
  console.log(element.getAttribute("data-value")); //it will generate =cDO4w67epn64o76
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myFunction(this)" data-value="%3DcDO4w67epn64o76">press</a>
```

...although I discourage using `onclick="..."` handlers. Instead:

```js
function linkHandler(e) {
  console.log(this.getAttribute("data-value"));
  e.preventDefault();
}


var links = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-value]");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  links,
  function(link) {
    link.addEventListener("click", linkHandler, false);
  }
);
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" data-value="%3DcDO4w67epn64o76">press</a>
```

Comment: your answer is perfect for me till now but in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization) , normalization will be applied by decoding unreserved encoded characters , and equal sign here is reserved . !

Answer (score 1):

A URL using the `javascript:` scheme is still a URL.

You've attempted to store a URL in a JavaScript string in a URL.

When decoding the outside URL into JavaScript, the percent encoded characters are decoded.

To do what you are attempting you need to convert any special characters (like `%`) in the JavaScript to URL encoding:

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction('%253DcDO4w67epn64o76')%3B">test</a>
```

---

You should only use this for creating bookmarklets though.

If you want to run JavaScript when something is clicked, then use a click event handler. You could use an `onclick` attribute, but `addEventListener` in the modern approach (for values of modern equal to "not the 1990s").

Likewise, if you aren't linking somewhere, don't use a link. Use a button instead.